# Add More Text fields

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Search Script in my spread sheet that I found on here. I understand most of it but not all. What I want is to add more of the text boxes that show that data. I tried adding the lines below but I get `TypeError: Cannot call method "add" of undefined. (line 41)`

Line 41 Contains `hpanel3.add(label4).add(label5).add(label6).add(label7)` Which is just a copy of the above code with different numbers. Script works without these lines.

```
// G. Variables
var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var lastrow = ss.getLastRow();
//
function onOpen() {
  var menuEntries = [ {name: "Search GUI", functionName: "searchUI"},
                     ];
  ss.addMenu("Search Utilities",menuEntries);// custom menu
}
// Build a simple UI to enter search item and show results + activate result's row
function searchUI() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setHeight(200).setWidth(600);
  app.setTitle("Search by anything");
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();
  var txtBox = app.createTextBox().setFocus(true);
  var label=app.createLabel(" Item to search for :")
  panel.add(label);
  txtBox.setId("item").setName("item");
//
  var label0=app.createLabel("Row").setWidth("40");
  var label1=app.createLabel("Name").setWidth("120");
  var label2=app.createLabel("ID").setWidth("120");
  var label3=app.createLabel("Street").setWidth("200");
  var hpanel = app.createHorizontalPanel();
  hpanel.add(label0).add(label1).add(label2).add(label3)
//
  var txt0=app.createTextBox().setId("lab0").setName("0").setWidth("40");
  var txt1=app.createTextBox().setId("lab1").setName("txt1").setWidth("120");
  var txt2=app.createTextBox().setId("lab2").setName("txt2").setWidth("120");
  var txt3=app.createTextBox().setId("lab3").setName("txt3").setWidth("250");
  var hpanel2 = app.createHorizontalPanel();
  hpanel2.add(txt0).add(txt1).add(txt2).add(txt3)
//                   
//
//  var label4=app.createLabel("Phone").setWidth("120");
//  var label5=app.createLabel("Pet Name").setWidth("120");
//  var label6=app.createLabel("Breed").setWidth("120");
//  var label7=app.createLabel("Gender").setWidth("120");
//  var hpanel = app.createHorizontalPanel();
//  hpanel3.add(label4).add(label5).add(label6).add(label7)
////
//  var txt4=app.createTextBox().setId("lab4").setName("txt4").setWidth("40");
//  var txt5=app.createTextBox().setId("lab5").setName("txt5").setWidth("120");
//  var txt6=app.createTextBox().setId("lab6").setName("txt6").setWidth("120");
//  var txt7=app.createTextBox().setId("lab7").setName("txt7").setWidth("250");
//  var hpanel3 = app.createHorizontalPanel();
//  hpanel4.add(txt4).add(txt5).add(txt6).add(txt7)
//
  var hidden = app.createHidden().setName("hidden").setId("hidden");
  var subbtn = app.createButton("next ?").setId("next").setWidth("250");
  var link = app.createAnchor('', '').setId('link');
  panel.add(txtBox);
  panel.add(subbtn);
  panel.add(hidden);
  panel.add(hpanel);
  panel.add(hpanel2);
//  panel.add(hpanel3);
//  panel.add(hpanel4);
  panel.add(link);
  var keyHandler = app.createServerHandler("click");
  txtBox.addKeyUpHandler(keyHandler)
  keyHandler.addCallbackElement(panel);
//
  var submitHandler = app.createServerHandler("next");
  subbtn.addClickHandler(submitHandler);
  submitHandler.addCallbackElement(panel);
//
  app.add(panel);  
  ss.show(app);
  }
//
function click(e){
   var row=ss.getActiveRange().getRowIndex();              
   var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
   var txtBox = app.getElementById("item");
   var subbtn = app.getElementById("next").setText("next ?")      
   var txt0=app.getElementById("lab0").setText('--');
   var txt1=app.getElementById("lab1").setText('no match').setStyleAttribute("background", "white");// default value to start with
   var txt2=app.getElementById("lab2").setText('');
   var txt3=app.getElementById("lab3").setText('');     
//   var txt4=app.getElementById("lab4").setText('');
//   var txt5=app.getElementById("lab5").setText('');
//   var txt6=app.getElementById("lab6").setText('');
//   var txt7=app.getElementById("lab7").setText('');
   var link=app.getElementById('link').setText('').setHref('')
   var item=e.parameter.item.toLowerCase(); // item to search for
   var hidden=app.getElementById("hidden")                  
   var data = sh.getRange(3,1,lastrow,18).getValues();// get the 18 columns of data
       for(nn=0;nn<data.length;++nn){ ;// iterate trough
         if(data[nn].toString().toLowerCase().match(item.toString())==item.toString()&&item!=''){;// if a match is found in one of the 18 fields, break the loop and show results
          txt0.setText(nn+3);
          txt1.setText(data[nn][0]).setStyleAttribute("background", "cyan");
          txt2.setText(data[nn][2]);
          txt3.setText(data[nn][4]);
//          txt4.setText(data[nn][5]);
//          txt5.setText(data[nn][6]);
//          txt6.setText(data[nn][7]);
//          txt7.setText(data[nn][8]);
          link.setText(data[nn][0]).setHref(data[nn][0]);
          sh.getRange(nn+3,1).activate();
          subbtn.setText("found '"+item+"' in row "+Number(nn+3)+", next ?");
          hidden.setValue(nn.toString())                                                                                  
          break
          }
      }
return app    ;// update UI
}
function next(e){
   var row=ss.getActiveRange().getRowIndex();              
   var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
   var txtBox = app.getElementById("item");
   var subbtn = app.getElementById("next").setText("no other match")      
   var hidden=app.getElementById("hidden");                  
   var start=Number(e.parameter.hidden)+1;//returns the last search index stored in the UI
   var item=e.parameter.item.toLowerCase(); // item to search for
   var txt0=app.getElementById("lab0");
   var txt1=app.getElementById("lab1").setStyleAttribute("background", "yellow");
   var txt2=app.getElementById("lab2");
   var txt3=app.getElementById("lab3");
   var link=app.getElementById('link').setText('').setHref('')
   var data = sh.getRange(3,1,lastrow,18).getValues();// get the 18 columns of data
       for(nn=start;nn<data.length;++nn){ ;// iterate trough
         if(data[nn].toString().toLowerCase().match(item.toString())==item.toString()&&item!=''){;// if a match is found in one of the 4 fields, break the loop and show results
          txt0.setText(nn+3);
          txt1.setText(data[nn][0]).setStyleAttribute("background", "cyan");
          txt2.setText(data[nn][2]);
          txt3.setText(data[nn][4]);
          link.setText(data[nn][0]).setHref(data[nn][0])
          sh.getRange(nn+3,1).activate();
          subbtn.setText("found '"+item+"' in row "+Number(nn+3)+", next ?");                                                                                               
          hidden.setValue(nn.toString())                                                                                  
          break
          }
      }
return app    ;// update UI
}
```

Any Help is greatly apperiated. Like I said, I understand a lot of whats going on but I could never do this from scratch. This is for a Dog License List. I am an Animal Control Officer and when I find a stray Dog my dispatcher will use this to find an owner to the dog doesn't have to go to the shelter.

Comment: hi, I'm the original author of this script, glad to see you use it ;-)  That said, you'll have to update the next() function as well with the new fields... don't forget it or you'll loose the prev/next functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Defined" means that a value has been given to a variable in the current scope. If you're watching in the debugger, you'll see all the variables that are "Declared" in scope, even if they have not yet been Defined.

You have the definitions of your various `hpanel`s happening in the wrong order. At Line 41, you haven't yet defined `hpanel3`. (The error message isn't lying to you!) It appears that you meant to define it in line 40, but instead you *redefined* `hpanel`.

Later, line 47 defines `hpanel3`, but then line 48 tries assigning to `hpanel4`, which isn't yet defined. This would give the same error.

<sup><sub>btw, you don't need to put comments to have blank lines... they can just be blank.</sub></sup>

Comment: Hi Mogsdad, You're right about your (very) small comment... As I mentioned in the other comment on this post I wrote this script a while ago and at that time I "hated" to see blank lines (way of speaking ^^)... now I'm getting grown up, I'm not afraid of emptiness anymore ! I suppose I may say I'm a big boy now ;-)